# Asp.net MVC-5 working with bootstrap toggle switch

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am working on asp.net MVC 5, referring to my question i have added a bootstrap toggle switch in my page, the razor syntax is bellow

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset style="height:60px">
    <legend style="text-align:center;  font-size:large; font-family:'Times New Roman'; background-color:#C8E6C9; color:red">Remote On/Off</legend>
    <input id="test_id" name="cmdName" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
</fieldset>
}
```

This razor syntax is placed in a partial view and is called in a layout

The generated Switch button is as follows

[image]

Now, i want to pass this On or Off value(string) to my action method.

For start i have placed a javascript event function and which simply shows me the alert box displaying On or Off with respective switch condition

My script is as follows

```
<script>     
    $("#test_id").on("change", function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            alert("ON");
          } else {
            alert("Off");              
        }
    });   </script>
```

For passing this **On** or **Off** i have searched many articles and found that ajax call is used for this purpose so i placed a ajax call in my if and else condition

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
                data: '{"cmdName": "On"}',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        } else {

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
                data: '{"cmdName": "Off"}',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

Bellow is my action method

```
public ActionResult MultiGraph(string search, string start_date, string cmdName , string End_date,int? page)
{
// i want to pass On or Off values based on switching in my string cmdName
}
```

Is there any other way rather than ajax call to do it? Or what should i do in my ajax call ?

**Updated Code**

In my script i have done the following

```
$("#test_id").on("change", function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            //alert("ON");
            var data = { cmdName: "On" }
        } else {
            //alert("Off");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")',
                data: data,
            });
        }
    });
```

See the bellow images

[image]

[image]

Getting null in `cmdName`

I am unable to pass them, i must be missing some thing which i don't know

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `data: {cmdName: "On"},` (no surrounding quotes). But do not add 2 ajax calls - simply use `if ($(this).is(":checked")) { var data = {cmdName: "On"} } else { ... }` and one ajax call with `data: data,` (and all your passing is a value for `cmdName` - the other parameters in your method will be `null`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke kindly see the updated code

Comment: No, the complete code is `var data = {}; if ($(this).is(":checked")) { data = {cmdName: "On"} } else { data =  {cmdName: "Off"}} $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("MultiGraph")', data: data });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke the ajax call is only on else part right ?

Comment: No, the ajax call is after the `if/else` block

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok let me have a try

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes it's working thanks alot :)